# Chevalley–Warning theorem's proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, finite-fields

I'm struggling to prove [Chevalley–Warning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem), i.e. only the part which shows that

> the number of common solutions ${\displaystyle (a_{1},\dots ,a_{n})\in \mathbb {F} ^{n}}$ is divisible by the characteristic ${\displaystyle p}$ of ${\displaystyle \mathbb {F} }$. Or in other words, the cardinality of the vanishing set of ${\displaystyle \{f_{j}\}_{j=1}^{r}}$ is ${\displaystyle 0}$ modulo ${\displaystyle p}$.

I'm looking for some reference to guide me, in English. The only source I found is the original [Chevalley's paper "Démonstration d'une hypothèse de M. Artin" (1935)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02940714), in French.

Best regards

Comment: Your quote of the theorem is incomplete.  Please quote the full theorem.

Comment: Serre's A course in Arithmetic has a proof, its clear but somewhat concise.

Comment: See also http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/SeminarOnCohomology/Ax.pdf (Page 256, Section 2).  Combine this proof with the proof you find in Wikipedia.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/legacy/13454/HT_W8_Testa.pdf

Comment: Doesn’t the link prove this? Is there a spot in that proof where you’re stuck?

Comment: There is also an elegant proof using the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz.  See Theorem 3.1 of https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf.

Comment: Would [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50679/11619) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1356155/11619) help?

Comment: Thank you all. 
In [Serre's "A Course in Arithmetic"](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~jlipman/MA598/Serre-Course%20in%20Arithmetic.pdf), in the lemma before Theorem 3 (see page 15), why the following is true? "If $u \ge 1$ and divisible by $q-1$, then $x^u = 1$ if $x ≠ 0$". Best regards

Comment: In [Wiki's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem#Proof_of_Warning's_theorem), why does the first part true? i.e. that for $i < q-1$ it holds that $\sum\limits_{x \in \mathbb F} x^i = 0$. Best regards